# Manipulate POST-Method with Python

Tags: python, http, post, seleniumwire

I want to use a POST-Method with an Parameter in Request Body. After some research I found the library seleniumwire.
I tried this:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver= webdriver.Firefox()

driver.header_overrides = {
'myfirstparamter': 'value'
}

driver.get('http://mywebsite.de')
driver.requests(method='POST', ??? thats the point where I dont know exactly how to keep going on.
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to use the `requests` library instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `seleniumrequests` it is much more easier (since seleniumwire is not only a requests library, but also has some other functions like binding, which will need other unwanted things to be implemented in your script). And why are you trying to send a `get` request then a `post` request, the later is enough to send parameters to host and get response.

Here is a simple script to post data using `seleniumrequests` library

```
from seleniumrequests import Firefox

driver = Firefox()
response = driver.request('POST', 'http://mywebsite.de', data={"parm1": "val1", "parm2": "val2"})
print(response)
```